# Partition a string in Rust

Tags: rust

Is there a mechanism in Rust to partition a string in to a list of equal length elements (either substrings or tuples / arrays of chars)?

I'd like to take a String `"abcdefghijkl"` and split it into a list like `["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh" "ij" "kl"]`

I don't need to see ways of doing this manually, I just want to know if there's a parallel to Clojure's `partition`:

```
user> (partition 2 "abcdefghijkl")
((\a \b) (\c \d) (\e \f) (\g \h) (\i \j) (\k \l))
```

Answer (score 6):

In the current version of Rust master (which should remain true in Rust 0.9), there is a method [`chunks`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/vec/trait.ImmutableVector.html#tymethod.chunks) on vectors and vector slices that iterates over the vector, returning equal-length vector slices until exhaustion. However, there are not any methods on strings or iterators in general to let you accomplish this.

To work around this, note that although Rust strings are not Rust vectors in and of themselves, they are backed by a vector of `u8` that contains the UTF-8 representation of the string. In addition, the `str` types offer methods to obtain different views of the string, in particular:

- [`as_bytes`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/str/trait.StrSlice.html#tymethod.as_bytes): Returns an immutable vector slice of the underlying UTF-8 byte vector (`&'a [u8]`). You can call `chunks` directly on this, but since you're iterating over bytes, this will only work if you know your string is entirely ASCII.
- [`chars`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/str/trait.StrSlice.html#tymethod.): Returns an *iterator* over the Unicode codepoints in the string, producing a stream of UTF-32 `char` values.

You can copy the values produced by an iterator into an owned, heap-allocated vector with the [`to_owned_vec`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.to_owned_vec) method, on which you can run `chunks`.

**EDIT:** This originally claimed that `chunks` existed in Rust 0.8. In actuality, the method name was `chunk_iter`. See the comments for more details.

Comment: Those methods don't appear to be in 0.8, although this was enough to get me on the right route.
Instead of `chunks` I found `chunk_iter` that gave me back a `ChunkIter`. I had to `clone()` that before I could do anything useful with it and then I ended up with this,

    `let bytes:&[u8] = "abcdef".as_bytes();
    let partitioned:ChunkIter<u8> = bytes.chunk_iter(2);
    for x in partitioned.clone()  {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }`

Comment: You can avoid the explicit type annotations and use from_utf8 to show the characters:

    `let bytes = "abcdef".as_bytes();`
    `let mut partitioned = bytes.chunks(2);`

    `for x in partitioned {`
        `println(from_utf8(x));`
    `}`
`}`
`

Comment: Also, you're not using master (you should always use master) if you don't have `chunks` and you can make the `partitoned` variable mutable instead of cloning (not sure what the best practice is here...).

Comment: @DanMidwood I think `chunks` was `chunk_iter` and `chars` was just `iter` in 0.8.

Comment: @IsaacAggrey Thanks. I'm just getting started with Rust and assumed 0.8 would be easier to learn from (more stable than) a floating head of master development. I might reconsider that now.

Comment: And the explicit type annotations, they're there mostly to assist my memory